# How to add contents through block after enabling the blog module in drupal 7

Tags: blocks, nodes

Currently creating a single page responsive business website. Planning to add blog link to our site. For that we enabled the core blog module and added data.
But we want to add the contents through block!!! can anyone specify me with a solution?

Comment: Do you mean you want the submit form for a blog entry to appear as a block that you can place somewhere on your site?

Comment: Actually the issue is ,i want to see all the blogs in blocks and display that not in home page as we are creating another link for it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, you want to display blog entries in a block on your website.

I haven't used the Blog module in a long while (it's functionality can be duplicated easily without enabling it), but I think the easiest way for you to do this is to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

1. Add a few blog entries
2. Create a new View that displays Content of type Blog Entry in a Block.
3. Views creates a new block, which you can place anywhere you'd like via the Block Admin page.

If you are unfamiliar with Views, you should watch or read some video tutorials. [This one](http://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7) is recent and seems to be up your alley.

[image: Adding a view that displays blog posts]